# Calculating the day of the year with QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, date, datetime

At QGIS 3.28.6 I have an attribute table containing a datetime field from which I need to populate an integer field that will contain the day of year (for example, 2/1/2018 would output to 32).

Using the Field Calculator, when I enter the expression `day("datetime_field")` the answer is the day of the month (here, 2/1/2018 outputs to the value of 1, instead of the desired 32).

Interestingly, the expression `week("datetime_field")` returns the week of the year, e.g. 1-52.  I need the same, only for day of the year.

A search through GIS SE, as well as an internet search, came up empty.

How to calculate day of the year from a datetime field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this expression, based on function [`age()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#age). The idea is the calculate the difference in days between your date and Jan 1 of that year.

The first argument is your date, and the second argument is the first day of the year: January 1, created as string, combined (concatenated with [pipes operator `||`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat)) with the year of your date, calculated with the [`year()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#year) function:

```
day (age (date, to_date (year (date) || '-01-01'))) + 1
```

*Calculating the day of the year for the 1st of each month + Dec. 31 results in different values for 2018 and 2020 (leap year, values from March on), as expected:*
[image]

Comment: Very good!  I might add one edit: the Field Editor requires that the date field (red text in your answer) needs to be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Double quotes are optional, but probably it's indeed better/good style to use them